# Get text from EditText and status of CheckBox then send these to a URL with HTTP POST

Tags: java, android, http-post

I have **1 Button**, **1 EditText** , **6 Checkbox** and **1 TextView (in another activity)**

I want these:
Firstly *onClick* the button, get text from **EditText**, save it to a variable and check if **Checkbox** are ticked or not, if checked generate *a varibale* and *setText* to **TRUE** else **FALSE**.

Secondly send 7 variables of **checkbox** and **EditText** to a URL via **HTTP POST** method. After that get server response and show it in **TextView** of another activity

This is my JAVA file but it doesn't work, Would anyone correct these codes.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import static com.royalrandhawa.untitled.R.id.mainSearch;

/**
 * Created by ROYAL on 10/11/2017.
 */

public class SurfAnony extends Activity {

    String one, two, three, four, five, six;
    CheckBox First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth;
    TextView content;
    Button search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.surfNowBtn);
    EditText query = (EditText) findViewById(mainSearch);
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.surf_anony);

        First = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.eurlchb);
        Second = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.epagechb);
        Third = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.alckchb);
        Fourth = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ftcchb);
        Fifth = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.djschb);
        Sixth = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dsbchb);

        //First CheckBox
        First.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (First.isChecked()) {
                    one = "true";
                } else {
                    one = "false";
                }
            }
        });

        //Second CheckBox
        Second.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Second.isChecked()) {
                    two = "true";
                } else {
                    two = "false";
                }
            }
        });

        //Third CheckBox

        Third.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Third.isChecked()) {
                    three = "true";
                } else {
                    three = "false";
                }
            }
        });

        //Fourth CheckBox

        Fourth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Fourth.isChecked()) {
                    four = "true";
                } else {
                    four = "false";
                }
            }
        });

        //Fifth CheckBox

        Fifth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Fifth.isChecked()) {
                    five = "true";
                } else {
                    five = "false";
                }
            }
        });

        //Sixth CheckBox

        Sixth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Sixth.isChecked()) {
                    six = "true";
                } else {
                    six = "false";
                }
            }
        });


        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    GetText();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    content.setText(" url exeption! ");
                }

            }
        });
}

    public void GetText() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        // Get user defined values
        String q = query.getText().toString();



        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("q", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("eurl", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(one, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("epage", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(two, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("alck", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(three, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("ftc", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(four, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("djs", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(five, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("dsb", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(six, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Send data
        try {

            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("my url here!");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        // Show response on activity
        content.setText(text);

    }

}
```

This is logCat

> 10-15 16:46:29.451 19130-19130/com.royalrandhawa.xemp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.royalrandhawa.xemp, PID: 19130
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.royalrandhawa.xemp/com.royalrandhawa.xemp.SurfAnony}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1899)
>                                                                               at com.royalrandhawa.xemp.SurfAnony.(SurfAnony.java:30)
>                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Put Log(); function at each condition (if, else) and look in LogCat where the problem is situated.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting error in GetText();

Try this:

```
public  class senddata extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    BufferedReader br=null;
    URL url;
    String txt="";
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {             //url of your php file
                url = new URL("http://192.168.43.226/check.php");
            } catch (MalformedURLException m1) {

                txt = "exception";
            }
            try {
                //establishing connection
                 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                //connection timeout
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                // appending the query parameteres with key
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("fname", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("lname",params[1])
                        .appendQueryParameter("email",params[2])
                        .appendQueryParameter("pass",params[3])
                        .appendQueryParameter("phone",params[4])
                        .appendQueryParameter("country",params[5]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                //starting output stream to upload datat to server
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                //writing the data
                wr.write(query);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                conn.connect();


        }catch (IOException e1){
            txt = "input";
        }try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection is established
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            txt= "exceptio";
        }

        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return txt;
            }







    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

you can execute this using :
     new senddata().execute("what ever you want to send in string");

Comment: just use this in the place of your getText() to send data to server